# Using substr to trim string on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, substr

I want to trim a string to a specified length. If the string is shorter, I don't want to do anything. I found a function substr() which does the job. However there is nothing in the Oracle documentation what happens if the string is shorter, than maximal length.

For example this:

```
select substr('abc',1,5) from dual;
```

returns 'abc', which is what I need.

I'd like to ask if this is safe, because the function seems not to be defined for this usage. Is there a better way how to truncate?

Comment: `SUBSTR`ing always subset of the String. So never going to be greater than the actual String.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an interesting question.  Surprisingly, the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm) doesn't seem to cover this point explicitly.

I think what you are doing is quite safe.  `substr()` is not going to "add" characters to the end of the string when the string is too short.  I have depended on this behavior in many databases, including Oracle, over time.  This is how similar functions work in other databases and most languages.

The one sort-of-exception would be when the original data type is a `char()` rather than `varchar2()` type.  In this case, the function would return a string of the same type, so it might be padded with spaces.  That, though, is a property of the type not really of the function.

Answer (score 18):

It is totally ok, but if you want, you can use this query:

```
select substr('abc',1,least(5,length('abc'))) from dual;
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to be absolutely certain that you won't end up with trailing blanks by using SUBSTR alone (you won't, but sometimes it's comforting be really sure) you can use:

```
SELECT RTRIM(SUBSTR('abc',1,5)) FROM DUAL;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 4):

It is better to use the below query

```
SELECT SUBSTR('abc',1,LEAST(5,LENGTH('abc'))) FROM DUAL;
```

Above query would either take the length of the string or the number 5 whichever is lower.

Comment: I meant, to be fool-proof and to be rest-assured without any doubts!